# Primefaces dialog + commandButton

Tags: jsf-2, dialog, primefaces, commandbutton

I'm trying to use primefaces `<p:dialog>` combined with `<p:commandButton>`. In my .xhtml page I have a picklist and commandButton which is used to show a dialog. Dialog displays datatable with target values from picklist. Dialog has two buttons: cancel and submit. My problem is that submit button is not fired. What's strange, commandButton out of dialog works.

Here's my .xhtml:

```
<body>
   <ui:composition template="./../resources/mainTemplate.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form>
                <p:dialog id="dlg" header="#{messages.chooseSkillLevel}" widgetVar="dlg" modal="true" dynamic="true">
                    <h:dataTable value="#{editSkills.skillsAndLevels}" var="skillslevel">
                        <h:column>
                            #{skillslevel.skill.umiejetnosc}
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{skillslevel.level}" >
                                <f:selectItems value="#{editSkills.levels}" var="level" itemLabel="#{level.stopien}" itemValue="#{level.id}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </h:column>
                    </h:dataTable>
                    <p:commandButton value="#{messages.confirm}" action="#{editSkills.showSkillsAndLevels}" oncomplete="dlg.hide();" />   THIS BUTTON IS NOT FIRED
                    <p:commandButton value="#{messages.cancel}" onclick="dlg.hide()"/>
                </p:dialog>
                <p:pickList value="#{editSkills.skills}" var="skill" effect="none"  
                itemValue="#{skill.id}" itemLabel="#{skill.umiejetnosc}"  
                showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" 
                addLabel="#{messages.add}" removeLabel="#{messages.remove}" removeAllLabel="#{messages.removeAll}" >  
                    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">#{messages.skillsList}</f:facet>  
                    <f:facet name="targetCaption">#{messages.yourSkills}</f:facet>
                    <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{editSkills.onTransfer}" /> 
                    <p:column style="width:100%;">  
                        #{skill.umiejetnosc}  
                    </p:column> 
                </p:pickList>
                <p:commandButton value="#{messages.confirm}" action="#{editSkills.afterSubmit}" update="dlg" oncomplete="dlg.show()" />   THIS BUTTON WORKS FINE
                <p:commandButton value="#{messages.cancel}" action="profile" immediate="true"/>
           </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
```

I've marked working button and not working one.
What do I have to do to make it working?

Comment: Have you looked at the console, its not making an ajax call? or is it simply not working? Try looking in firebug if its sending data to server, or is the AJAX firing and the method `#{editSkills.showSkillsAndLevels}` is not being called at all? Also check if firebug is not showing any JS errors.

Comment: @Mindwin it seems that it's not being called at all. Can't see any JS errors too.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can try either of the following , I vote number one, it's a cleaner design IMO

1. Bring the `<p:dialog/>` outside of the general `<h:form/>` and put an `<h:form/>` *inside* it instead

   ```
     <p:dialog id="dlg" header="#{messages.chooseSkillLevel}" widgetVar="dlg" modal="true" dynamic="true">
         <h:form>
               <h:dataTable value="#{editSkills.skillsAndLevels}" var="skillslevel">
                   <h:column>
                       #{skillslevel.skill.umiejetnosc}
                   </h:column>
                   <h:column>
                       <p:selectOneMenu value="#{skillslevel.level}" >
                           <f:selectItems value="#{editSkills.levels}" var="level" itemLabel="#{level.stopien}" itemValue="#{level.id}" />
                       </p:selectOneMenu>
                   </h:column>
               </h:dataTable>
               <p:commandButton value="#{messages.confirm}" action="#{editSkills.showSkillsAndLevels}" oncomplete="dlg.hide();" />   THIS BUTTON IS NOT FIRED
               <p:commandButton value="#{messages.cancel}" onclick="dlg.hide()"/>
              </h:form>
           </p:dialog>
   ```
2. Add `appendToBody="false"` to the `<p:dialog/>` to ensure the dialog is rendered within the html form in the DOM instead of being auto-relocated to end of HTML body. But this may cause inconsistent rendering in various browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I did what you have told me to do, but now I'm getting this error:
`/user/editSkills.xhtml @39,121 itemValue="#{skill.id}": The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'id'.` What is strange I think it's connected with picklist and it's weird, cause picklist works fine. What should I do?

Comment: @AjMeen, that's a different issue altogether,probably caused by the fact that `#{skill.id}` and `#{skillslevel.level}` are not the same datatype(one of them is a string, the other is something else).  But now your commandButton is definitely firing.

Comment: `#{skillslevel.level}` has nothing to do with this error, cause even if I remove `skilsslevel` part the error still shows up. I just probably need a converter. Anyway thanks for help!

Comment: @AjMeen, You're welcome. You should only need a converter if `itemValue` is a POJO/complex type. Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13710569/1530938). The question directly correlates to yours

Comment: i am having the same problem, tried this but didn't work:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350850/pdialog-form-submission-doesnt-invoke-action-method?lq=1

Answer (score 5):

```
<p:commandButton  value="Cancel" oncomplete="PF('yourDialogWidgedVarName').hide();" process="@this"  />
```

Make sure to use **'** when u call the widgetVar name. You can also use immediate="true" or process="@this".

Comment: you shouldn't need immediate="true" or process="@this".
However your answer had the quick bit of information I needed. Thanks!